# Chrome app jquery AJAX request not sending custom headers

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

I'm developing a Chrome app that makes a series of requests to my API using jquery.ajax. With a url permission for the api set in the manifest, this works just fine:

```
"permissions": [ 
    "https://example.com/*",
    "http://example.com/*"
]
```

However, when I try to upload this to the Chrome developer dashboard, I get the error:

```
The field permissions.https://example.com/ is not allowed in manifest.
```

I have assumed this is because Chrome apps are moving to a CORS model, although the url permission is still [shown in the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/permissions). I'm trying to implement CORS.

```
{
    "name": "My Extensions",
    "version": "1.0.7.5",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "app": {
        "launch": {
            "local_path": "pages/index/index.html"        
        }
    },
    "description": "Extension description.",
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; connect-src self https://example.com http://example.com",
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/msp-16.png",
        "128": "images/msp-128.png",
        "256": "images/msp-256.png"
    },
    "minimum_chrome_version": "14",
    "permissions": [ 
        "tts",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "storage"
    ]
}
```

And the ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    async: false,
    headers: {
        'apikey': 'myapikey'
    },
    url: 'https://example/api/auth/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        data: xmlToSubmit
    },
    success: function(xml) {

        //Do the thing

    },
    error: function(xhr) {

        //Do the other thing

    }
});
```

I've read lots of docs including [HTML Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-cross-domain-from-chrome-extensions). I'm sending a custom header 'apikey'. Server currently configured as:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "apikey"
```

When I make a request in from the app, an error is returned as the apikey header has not been sent. I get the expected xml error message that the api generates. I've  checked using Fiddler, and the apikey header is not being sent. I can send successful requests to my api with other Chrome extension REST clients, and I don't need to set the server headers for other apps sending requests to the api, nor when I used the original permissions.

What am I missing? IS it just the preflight failing? Have I missed something obvious in the original permissions that would allow it to upload?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question here is.

Comment: Aha. This is interesting. You manifest corresponds to a "legacy packaged app", since it has `app.launch` key as opposed to `app.background` key. [This blog post](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/11/restricting-extension-apis-in-legacy.html) explains why your initial manifest doesn't work. Is there a reason you're not using a new-style Chrome App?

Comment: Curly brackets won't load, should be square brackets: [link]https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest

Comment: I know, it was a stupid guess.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why Chrome/jquery does not appear to be sending the custom headers...

Comment: And [this blog post](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/06/migrate-your-legacy-packaged-apps-to.html) basically says that legacy packaged apps are no longer accepted.

Comment: @Xan I've seen that post. I've been working on this for a while, it's really historic. The initial manifest works in the sense perfectly when loaded as an unpackaged app, but is rejected by the Developer Dashboard when uploaded as zip.

Comment: I would assume they either now restrict even existing apps, or it's a bug in Web Store. The latter is quite possible. When did you last publish an update?

Comment: It's the first time I've tried to publish. About a month ago.

Comment: Working in Chrome != publishing on Chrome Web Store. Typically the deprecation plan goes in phases, one removing publishing support, and the other finally removing client support. Guess which phase we're in now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved with what @xan and @sowbug hinted at. By changing the manifest to call a launch background script as a 'new' packaged app, and making some minor code changes, this worked a dream:

```
"app": {
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["launch.js"]
    }
},
```

The url permission to access the api was added back into the manifest

```
"permissions": [ 
    ...
    "https://example.com/",
    "http://example.com/",
    ....
],
```

I also had to *remove* this setting from the jquery AJAX request:

```
async: false;
```

after [I read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365017/chrome-packaged-apps-not-working-with-jquery-and-jquery-mobile).